# Ecplise JPA Adding new parent object

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa, entity-relationship, cascade

I'm trying to build an application with Netbean. I use Eclipse IDE & JPA API. the Entities is like this:

NATS.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "NATS")
Public Class NATS implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Integer code;
  private String nName;
  @Column(name = "cap_id") // for foreign key purpose
  private Integer capId;
  @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
  @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "cap_id" )
  private City capital;
  public City getCapital(){
      return this.capital;
  }
  public void setCapital (City newcapital){
      this.capital = newcapital;
  }
  ... some gets & sets methods
}
```

City.java

```
@Entity
public class City implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  private String cityName;    
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Basic(optional = false)
  private Integer cityId;
  public String getCityName() {
      return cityName;
  }
  public void setCityName(String newcityName) {
      this.cityName = newcityName;
  }    
  public City(String ctname) {
      this.cityName = ctname;
  }
  public Integer getcityId() {
      return cityId;
  }
  public void setcityId(Integer ctId) {
      this.cityId = ctId;
  }

}
```

When i want to add new pair of NATS & City, i use this :

somebean.java

```
@Stateless
public class somebean {
  @PersistenceContext(unitName = "TestLocal")
  private EntityManager em;

  public NATs insertNewCC(String capitalname, String countryname){
    City newcapital = new City(capitalname );
    NATS newcountry = new NATS();
    newcountry.setNationName(countryname);
    newcountry.setCapital(newcapital);
    em.persist(newcountry); // both objects persisted well, with "capId" still null
    return newcountry;
  }

  public void updateCapitalId(Nations country){
    country.setCapitalId(country.getCapital().getcityId());
    em.merge(country);
  }
}
```

Here is the service:

genericResource.java

```
@Path("generic")
public class GenericResource {

@Context
private UriInfo context;
@EJB
private somebean r;

@GET
@Path("/inscountry")
@Produces("application/json")
public List<NATS> insCountry( @QueryParam("countryname") String countryname, @QueryParam("capitalname") String capitalname){      
    NATS newcountry = r.insertNewCC(capitalname, countryname);
    //r.updateCapitalId(newcountry);   <-- i want to avoid using this line
    List<NATS> result= r.getListNATS();
    return result;
}
```

When i comment the line : r.updateCapitalId(newcountry);
i get a pair of country and capital city with a relation displayed correctly in JSON, but when the session closes. it losses the relation because the foreign key is not saved. the capId in NATs entity is null after persist completed. So i need 1 persist & 1 merge to complete this. is there a better solution beside using that line i commented? 
Thank you.

Comment: are you sure this is your code..? it looks like it won't even compile & nesting entities is a very bad thing to do, can't you have separate classes for each entities ?

Comment: it's quoted from different .java files. i actually write each entities in different files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redesign your entity NATS like this :

```
package com;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "NATS")

public class NATS
    implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer code;
    private String name;
    // for foreign key purpose
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "cap_id")
    private City capital;

    public City getCapital()
    {
        return this.capital;
    }

    public void setCapital(City newcapital)
    {
        this.capital = newcapital;
    }

    public Integer getCode()
    {
        return this.code;
    }

    public void setCode(Integer code)
    {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

and then code for execution will remain same :

```
    City newcapital = new City(capitalname);
    NATS newcountry = new NATS();
    newcountry.setName(countryname);
    newcountry.setCapital(newcapital);
    this.entityManager.persist(newcountry);
```

Comment: If you observe , i have removed cap_id explicit variable from NATS.java and  change annotation and it will work as you are expecting.

Comment: Also add one default constructor to City.java as it will be required.

Comment: Thank you. This is what i've been looking for.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try to use indents and a formatter because your code is a mess. Second you want to save two entities (NATS and Country) so you must to uncomment the line where you update the city or persist one by one. If you are starting a new application I recommend you to use Spring boot and it's SpringRepository Interface to make  those kind of things easier and clear.

Comment: Thank's for your answer. I've added identation on NATS entity, that's the only part i found that need better identation. I assume that you suggest me to keep the "update capitalId" part. I really appreciate your answer.  :)